# REST API and security

Tags: json, api, rest, authentication, authorization

I'm planning on doing a uniform JSON REST API for both my javascript based web app and as an API for other developers to use.

What I would like to do, is have my js app authenticate users using a username/password and allow them to access their own private resources. When the API is going to be accessed by other dev's, I'd like to allow them to access public resources (while still being able to track their API usage) and also let them access user's private data   with the users permission (authorization ?).

Now, how would I go building such an API? What libraries/protocols/... would be the best at this?

Thanks.

Comment: check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715863/implementing-security-in-rest

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I could use HTTP Basic Auth to authenticate a user from my app, but how could I go about authorizing access to other apps, as giving a password (by a user) to a 3rd party isn't really the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really check out Oauth. Take a look at http://oauth.net